# NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn confusion

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to add a `NSDate` object to my `NSPointerArray` configured with (`NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn`) option:

```
NSDate *today= [NSDate date];

NSPointerArray *p_arr = [NSPointerArray pointerArrayWithOptions:NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn];

[p_arr addPointer:(void *)today];

 // comparing addresses;

 NSLog(@" Addresses are: %p  , %p " , today , [p_arr pointerAtIndex:0]);

//Addresses are:0x1004005d0  , 0x1004005d0
```

but as I know with "NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn" the object in my pointer array should be a new copy not a shared object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in
[Friday Q&A 2010-05-28: Leopard Collection Classes](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-05-28-leopard-collection-classes.html),
the `NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn` options causes the object pointers to be "copied" using the
`NSCopying` protocol. This does not necessarily mean that a new object is created.

In the case of *immutable* objects (such as`NSDate`), `NSCopying` *can* be implemented by retaining
the original instead of create a new copy. And this is what happens
in your case:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *today2 = [today copy];

NSLog(@"%p %p", today, today2);
// Output: 0x1001040f0 0x1001040f0
```

Comment: in that case what is difference between "NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory" and "NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn" because both of them will retain new added object?

Comment: As I understand it, those options are independent of each other. "NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory" is a "memory option" and means (in connection with the default "NSPointerFunctionsObjectPersonality"), that the object is retained. "NSPointerFunctionsCopyIn" causes `copyWithZone` to be called on the object. `copyWithZone` might return a new object or simply retain the passed object (see NSCopying protocol documentation). If you test your code with a NSMutableString, you would get a different object.

Comment: @user3061088: What exactly are you worried about? An NSDate object cannot be mutated, so it should not matter if you get a pointer to the original object, or a pointer to a new object.

Comment: I got the point , if I add a mutable object , it will create new object but if I add a immutable one it will retain the old one, thanx buddy